# Can't get rid(find) of this margin. Please help!

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I isntalled the Professional theme and Content Glider - all very simple. I got rid of titles and all in the glider, but I can't find the code where the blank line or margin is created. Drupal is new for me. Look and you'll see right away: http://www.aironfix.eu
The slider content-type has no body just title and image. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Advising on how to use dev tools or how to locate a CSS class/style in a website is off-topic here, as it's not inherently related to Drupal.

Comment: Ok. I'll keep that in mind. I didn't realize at first that it might be template styling related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside professional_theme/style.css line no 727 there is css rule,

```
.node {
margin: 20px 0;
}
```

thats create the margin of 20px white margin.

Comment: Got it!
Some more pixels left. I scanned through the css and nothing.

Comment: same css line no:- 94   media="all"
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
margin-bottom: 6px;
font-weight: bold;
/* line-height: 1.62em; */
}

Comment: margin-bottom: 6px is ur last px

Comment: Super. I don't know how you did it so fast. Thank you very much!